# Как отключить нажатие button клавишей пробел?

Tags: css, button

По клику на `button` добавлется `class`. После клика фокус постоянно на `button` (даже если кликнуть в другое место), нажав пробел (спайс на клаве), класс добавляется/удаляется. Как удалить предотвратить это/ как отключить это?

Comment: Тащи код. Сюда.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev это целая цепочка анимационного меню. Там стилей только на 1000 строчек. Действительно это нужно?

Comment: Если мой ответ не подходит, то вам надо как-то показать и объяснить то, что нужно. Я не умею читать мысли людей)

Comment: @Ученик, при любой задаче можно создать [mcve]. Именно это у тебя и запрашивается, в качестве уточнения вопроса.

Comment: @yar85 Спасибо я учту это в следующий раз

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте кнопке добавить `onclick="this.blur();"`

```
<button type="button" onclick="this.blur();>
```

Или то же самое, но без добавления `onclick`

```
$('button').mouseup(function() { this.blur() })
```

Если же вам надо отключать пробел когда кнопка с фокусом то:

```
$("button:focus").on({
    if (e.which === 32){
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Я поставил плюсик за Ваш труд, но я уже выполнил аналогичный код на чистом яваскрипт. И я не стану подключать библеотеку ради 5 строчек кода) Спасибо за уделенное мне время

Answer (score 0):

Из твоего вопроса я понял, что нужно убрать outline. Если я неправильно тебя понял, то переизложи свои мысли так, чтобы тебя поняли. Если правильно то:

```
button, button:focus, button:hover, button:active {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Это стандартная процедура у меня (отключать оутлайн и бордер). Что не понятного в вопросе. Фокус постоянно на кнопке после клика на нее. Если после клика нажать на пробел, то класс, добавляемый js будет добавляться и еще раз по нажатию добавляться.

Comment: @Ученик Еще раз - я не умею читать мысли. Хочешь решение проблемы - конкретный пример. Это ведь твои проблемы.